# Conflict when calling two versions of jQuery in Wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, filter, preview

I have integrated the jQuery quicksand filter technique to my theme which uses jQuery 1.7.2 (based on [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)). I am trying to extend this by adding a "preview" functionality which uses jQuery 1.9.1 (based on [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/comment-page-6/#comments)). I have been able to successfully integrate this, however unfortunately when calling jQuery 1.9.1 my filter functionality stops working. It is noted in the filter tutorial that you need to revert back to the older 1.7.2 version in order for that to work, however I need 1.9.1 for the preview functionality..

Is there any way to call both versions of jQuery or is there any other way of going about this to overcome the "conflict"? I appreciate any insight. Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery's noconflict mode, and pass true parameter to it in case your second functionality will use 'jQuery' global variable except for '$'

Check out more information about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure exactly how to use noconflict with my code but I will give it a go. Thanks again!